# How to get a radio group's selected value in Dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I need to do a project using Dojo and I am totally confused how to deal with a group of radios. Consider an example like following; it is easy to get the selected value by using:

```
$('input[name=map]').on('change', function() {
    console.info($(this).val());
});
```

How can I do this in Dojo?

```
require([ "dojo/dom",
          "dojo/on",
          "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, on) {

   //------?

});
```

```js
// jQuery way

$('input[name=map]').on('change', function() {
    console.info($(this).val());
});

// Dojo Way ???
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="map" value="dark"> Dark<br>
<input type="radio" name="map" value="streets"> Street<br>
<input type="radio" name="map" value="terrain"> Terrain
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `dojo/query` for it. This should do it.

```js
    // Dojo Way:
   require(["dojo/on", "dojo/query", "dojo/domReady!"],
  function(on, query) {
   query("[name='map']").map(function(radio){
    on(radio, "change", function(evt){
     console.log(this.value);
    })
   })
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.11.2/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="map" value="dark"> Dark<br>
<input type="radio" name="map" value="streets"> Street<br>
<input type="radio" name="map" value="terrain"> Terrain
```